# One form that needs two actions (one local, one remote)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read many links and tried many examples but still can't seem to get this working.  Any help and suggestions would be most appreciated.

I have one form that needs two actions:

1. Send an email with all form data to a given user email address (can
   do on own host)
2. Submit all form data to external server (CRM server)
   (no edit ability on external server

Upon completion of these two actions, a thank you page will be shown.

My thoughts at the moment are to create two forms (only one will be visible to the user).

HTML form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="">
  form1: Last Name: <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="Last Name" class="copy" value="from A"/>
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2" action="externalhost.html">
  <input type='text' name='returnURL' value='thankyou.php'>
  form2: Last Name: <input type="text" name="Last Name" id="Last Name" class="copy" value="target A" />
</form>
<input id="myButton" type="submit" value="hit me..." >
```

When the user enters the data and hits submit, all the data will be copied over to the second form.

```
function form2form(aF1, aF2) { 
 var selection = "#" + aF1 + " .copy";
 jQuery(selection).each(function() {
     document.forms[aF2].elements[jQuery(this).attr('name')].value = jQuery(this).val();
   });           
}
```

Then submit "form1" to own server to create and send email.

Then submit "form2" to external host to enter into that CRM system.  One field in "form2" will be a return URL which will be the thankyou page.

The logical,straightforward method,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
  jQuery('#myButton').click(function() {
    form2form ('form1', 'form2' );
    jQuery('#form1').submit(); 
    jQuery('#form1').submit(); 
  });
});
```

unfortunately, doesn't work.

My current jquery code also isn't working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
 jQuery("#myButton").livequery('click', function() { 
     var form = jQuery("#form2");
    var action = form.attr("action");
    var serialized_form = form.serialize();
    jQuery.post(action, serialized_form, submit_first);
  });
});


function submit_first(val) {
   jQuery("#form1").submit();
}
```

If you can direct me towards a workable solution, it would really help.  I've been having headaches over this one for far too long.

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the internet. Use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send the data to your server.  Then Transfer over to the external server.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is submit the form via ajax to both servers.

Something like:

```
jQuery("#form1").submit(function() {
  data = jQuery(this).serialize();
  jQuery.post('internal_server', data);
  jQuery.post('external_server', data);

  //redirect to thank you page, etc.
  return false; // Prevent normal form submission
});
```